# How to use glyphicons and font awesome icons simultaneously in free jqgrid toolbar

Tags: css, jqgrid, font-awesome, glyphicons, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid has big FontAwesome standard and user defined buttons with text defined like

```
    $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {
        iconsOverText: true,
        caption: '<span class="ui-pg-button-text">Pay</span>',
        buttonicon: 'fa-flag',
    });
```

I tried to add Glyphicon button using

```
    $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {
        iconsOverText: true,
        caption: '<span class="ui-pg-button-text">Pay</span>',
        buttonicon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download'
    });
```

but button is aligned differently:

[image]

I also tried

```
        buttonicon: 'glyphicon-cloud-download'
```

In this case rectangle appears instead of button.
How to use both fonts simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question don't includes enough implementation details. If one just use the code in standard free jqGrid then one will don't see any `glyphicon` icon because `fa` class are added too. If one would remove `fa` class and the button (the `<span>` with icon classes) will have `ui-pg-button-icon-over-text fa-lg fa-fw glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download` callses then I don't see and problem with glyphicon position. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/glyphicon.htm) as an example, which results looks like

[image]

So it should be a problem with **other CSS rules** which you use. I suppose that you need just to add one more CSS rule which fixes your custom CSS settings:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-button span.glyphicon {
    margin-top: ???px; /* SET value/values instead of ???, -5px, for example */
}
```

which would specify new value for `margin-top`. The value could be negative if required. You should just choose the value of margin which corresponds other CSS settings which you use. You can use Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to analyse which CSS rules will be applied on the icon and to overwrite there with your custom rules.